# Executing Angular.js-controller method on element shown

Tags: ajax, angularjs

How to execute controllers method on element shown. 
I have a tabs, and i want load data when user open a tab, if i using ng-init, information loads after page loading.

```
var systemSettingsController = manageApp.controller("SystemSettingsController", [
    "$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.tab = 1;
        $scope.initTab = function(tab) {
            $scope.tab = tab;
        };
    }
]);
var emailManagementController = manageApp.controller("EmailManagementController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.smtpServer = "";
        $scope.smtpLogin = "";
        $scope.smtpPassword = "";
        this.init = function() {
            $http.get("/api/EmailSettings")
                .then(function(res) {
                    var obj = angular.fromJson(res.data);
                    $scope.smtpServer = obj["Email.SmtpServer"];
                    $scope.smtpLogin = obj["Email.SenderAddress"];
                    $scope.smtpPassword = obj["Email.SenderPassword"];
                });
        };
...
```

I want execute method init (EmailManagementController) without using ng-init, and at the moment when this element is displayed on the screen, that is, its display will change to a property different from none.

Comment: Use the attribute ng-click="your_function_from_ctrl()"

Comment: in my application tab list and tab contents placing in different controllers.

Comment: Put the code man please, not clear at all for me...

Comment: Code added to post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs

basically you have each tabs (as view) associated with its controller.

```
$stateProvider.state('user', {
      url:         '',
      controller: 'UserCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'example.html'
    }).state('user.settings', {
      url:         '/user/settings',
      templateUrl: 'user/settings.html'
    })
```

the controller initialize when the tab (view) active